# Aurelia build using cli produces different results on different platforms

Tags: jenkins, aurelia

I'm trying to setup a jenkins job to automate builds of our aurelia app. When I build the app locally it works 100%, but when I build it on jenkins using the same process, then the files in the script directory is different.

I'm running Debian testing on my laptop. The Jenkins is a docker image running on Rancher.

When I test the build with jenkins, I get the following error:

```
http://localhost/src/main.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
vendor-bundle.js:2 Error: Script error for "main"(…)r @ vendor-bundle.js:2
```

Both my local environment and jenkins have the following tools and versions:

```
node: 6.9.1
npm: 3.10.8
aurelia: 0.22.0
```

The app is written in typescript.

we are also using aurelia-cli to build the app using : "au build --env prod"

The process we use to build the app:

```
npm install aurelia-cli
npm install
typings install
au build --env prod
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: Perhaps, another good place for this would be at the Aurelia CLI issues list. https://github.com/aurelia/cli/issues

Comment: Thanks, I added a bug on aurelia-cli: https://github.com/aurelia/cli/issues/424